# no module named Zope.interface error when using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, twisted, zope.interface

I have created a modbus server script using twisted and few other modules.
In Anaconda spyder tool, the script works fine but when i create exe file using cx_freeze tool, i get the below error.

```
Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface
```

Please help me finding a solution for this.

**Note: I have installed twisted and other modules using pip install from anaconda command prompt**

Comment: This is basically the same issue as the one others have had with `py2exe`, `pyinstaller`, and `py2app`.  Please see the referenced duplicate and reopen if it doesn't address your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the required version on module using pip:

```
pip install zope.interface
```

Also force reinstall using pip:

```
pip install 'zope.interface==3.6.0' --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Please don't use `==3.6.0`. Just `pip install zope.interface`; there are much more recent, and better, versions available.